# How do market cap websites obtain their list of coins?

Tags: market, coinmarketcap-com

Do they manually research and enter them into the database or do the coin developers contact the websites?

Answer (score 1):

They will usually scrape various exchange APIs/websites for tickers and names.

Comment: Thanks.  That is how I have been going about it but it's quite time consuming.  Maybe that's why they charge for the data afterwards.

Comment: You should be able to automate it

Comment: I am to a point.  each exchange API has different keys and such.  I may just stick to using the 5 or 6 high volume exchanges, it'll be relatively accurate.